# R/Stata: Remove persons without data

Tags: r, stata, data-science

I have a data project and have a problem with my panel set.

I want to remove "persons" who have no data about the variable "car"
In my example person 3 should me removed, but person 1 which has some data about car should stay in the set

Tried it with R/plyr and Stata but nothing seems to work.
The data set is 400,000 rows long btw

Data example:

```
person_id  year  car 
1   2000    1   
1   2001    nA  
1   2002    1   
1   2003    nA  
2   1998    1   
2   1999    0   
2   2000    0   
3   2003    nA  
3   2004    nA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `library(dplyr)`, the newer version of `library(plyr)`:

```
datf <- read.table(text = "person_id  year  car 
1   2000    1   
                   1   2001    nA  
                   1   2002    1   
                   1   2003    nA  
                   2   1998    1   
                   2   1999    0   
                   2   2000    0   
                   3   2003    nA  
                   3   2004    nA", header = TRUE)

# adjust to true NA values for R
datf$car <- gsub("nA", NA, datf$car)

# To keep only the people that don't have all NA values for car
library(dplyr)

datf %>% group_by(person_id) %>%
    filter(!all(is.na(car)))

# result
      person_id  year   car
      <int> <int> <chr>
1         1  2000     1
2         1  2001  <NA>
3         1  2002     1
4         1  2003  <NA>
5         2  1998     1
6         2  1999     0
7         2  2000     0
```

Comment: thank you very much <br>
dplyr seems to be a powerfull library, can you recommend a good introduction ?

Comment: the [dplyr cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf) is great and the [R for DataScience](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/) book is fantastic for more depth

Comment: thanks for the resources <br>
..but lets say that the NA is a number like "2".. would this be correct <br>
filter(!any(car=="2")) ?

Comment: also tried with any... but the number of observations is different between the is.na filter and the any filter

Comment: so if you convert the "nA" entries to "2", does this work `filter(!all(car == 2))`?

Answer (score 0):

In Stata, assuming you have translated `car` into a numeric variable with Stata numeric missing values where you now have nA.

```
. by person_id (year), sort: egen tokeep = count(car)

. list, clean noobs

    person~d   year   car   tokeep  
           1   2000     1        2  
           1   2001     .        2  
           1   2002     1        2  
           1   2003     .        2  
           2   1998     1        3  
           2   1999     0        3  
           2   2000     0        3  
           3   2003     .        0  
           3   2004     .        0  

. drop if tokeep==0
(2 observations deleted)

. drop tokeep

. list, clean noobs

    person~d   year   car  
           1   2000     1  
           1   2001     .  
           1   2002     1  
           1   2003     .  
           2   1998     1  
           2   1999     0  
           2   2000     0
```

If you insist on keeping your current string-based coding for `car`,

```
by person_id (year), sort: egen tokeep = sum(cond(car=="nA",0,1))
```

should do the trick, although I didn't test it.